# Could there be a way to associate similar questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Recently I asked the following question:

- [Does the distance between nodes effect the advance of the Rebel Fleet?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145569/does-the-distance-between-nodes-effect-the-advance-of-the-rebel-fleet)

In my question I cited that I had found an read:

- [What factors influence the speed of the rebel fleet?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83349/what-factors-influence-the-speed-of-the-rebel-fleet)

However, my question was later closed (rightly so) because it was a duplicate of:

- [Is rebel advancement determined by the distance between two beacons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102669/is-rebel-advancement-determined-by-the-distance-between-two-beacons)

I know that there is an area on the page that shows Similar Questions, but those appear to be more random (based on tags). What if there was a way to link questions That have a common thread (a more direct relationship than having the same tag)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Link it in a comment, and it'll show up in the sidebar.

Comment: It will. This is actually also the proposed solution to the "can't close as dupe because none is answered" problem.

Comment: I see, it shows up under its own header: Linked.